# Access Query - Select count distinct per record on multiple tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a query (concatenated inside a VB string):

```sql
SELECT a.table_no as tbl, COUNT(b.table_no) as total_call_count,
       AVG(TimeValue(c.service_time) * 86400) as total_time
FROM table_button_link a, button_log b, service_time_log c 
WHERE b.table_no = c.table_no 
 AND Format(b.transaction_datetime,""DD/MM/yyyy"") = '" & Date.Now.ToString("d") & "' "
 AND b.type <> 2 AND b.table_no = a.table_no AND c.table_no = a.table_no 
GROUP BY a.table_no
```

I want to count the `tbl_no` from the table `button_log` but it returns like this:

```
|tbl_no  | total_call_count | total_time |
|   1    |      4661        |   7.2134   |
|   2    |       5          |     3      |
|   3    |      576         |   9.33333  |
```

My desired output is like this:

```
|tbl_no  | total_call_count | total_time |
|   1    |       5          |   7.2134   |
|   2    |       1          |     3      |
|   3    |       3          |   9.33333  |
```

`button_log` looks like something like this:

```
| ID | table_no | type | transaction_datetime    |
| 1  |   1      |  1   | 28/07/2017 10:41:34 AM  |
| 1  |   1      |  2   | 28/07/2017 10:42:22 AM  |
| 2  |   1      |  1   | 28/07/2017 10:42:25 AM  |
| 3  |   2      |  1   | 24/07/2017 10:41:47 AM  |
```

`table_button_link` is like this:

```
| ID | table_no | button_no |
| 1  |   1      |   1       |
| 2  |   2      |   2       |
```

And `service_time_log` is like :

```
| ID | table_no | service_time | transaction_date       |
| 1  |    1     |  00:00:04    | 28/07/2017 10:42:22 AM |
| 1  |    2     |  00:00:05    | 28/07/2017 10:50:43 AM |
```

I think it counts all records. I tried using `COUNT(DISTINT b.table_no)` but I guess MS Access can't do that. How will I achieve this? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add more group by clause. How many columns you have in table button_log and sample data from same table would be good to share here.

Comment: @Prathyush i've updated the question.

Comment: Can you explain what the desired *total_call_count* column means? Is that distinct count of *ID* or *button_no* for each *table_no*?